# Getinspector in Sending Outlook appointment invitation through shared folder with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

Dear Stackoverflow Communities,

As you can see, I am newbie in this forum. Lately, I have been learning VBA by doing with the guide from internet forum. Most of the time, the available Q&As in stackoverflow do help me solving my challenges. However, I have this one which I can't find the solution and reason until now.

My goal is to send an outlook appointment through a shared folder and use getinspector to copy formatted cell contain from excel workbook to created outlook appointment. Everything works well if I did every task separately. When I integrate the code, the getinspector doesn't seem to work anymore. Following is the code that I used (please pardon me if the code looks not professional as I have been learning VBA by myself with the help of Forums):

```
Sub VBA_Appointment()

Dim objOL   As outlook.Application
Dim objAppt As outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objRecip As outlook.recipient
Dim strName As String
Dim wrdrng As Word.Range
Dim Doc As Word.document

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Const olAppointmentItem = 1
Const olFolderCalender = 9

Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objAppt = objOL.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
Set Doc = objAppt.GetInspector.WordEditor
Set objNS = objOL.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNS.Folders

strName = "John Smith"

Set objRecip = objNS.CreateRecipient(strName)
Set objFolder = objNS.GetsharedDefaultFolder(objRecip, olFolderCalender)

With objAppt
.Subject = "Testing"
.MeetingStatus = 1
.RequiredAttendees = ""
.Start = Now
.Location = ""
.BusyStatus = 1 '0=free;1=Tentative;2=Busy
'Copy desired data from EXCEL sheet and paste on the opened OUTLOOK Appointment
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B50").Copy
Set wrdrng = Doc.Range
.Display
wrdrng.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set objAppt = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
Set objNS = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objRecip = Nothing

End Function
```

So, I would definitely be grateful if someone VBA profis can point out the reason why and explain the reason why the paste from the clipboard, which is the last step, doesn't work in this case.

Many Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working for me, but it's probably because of available memory, processor speed, etc -since you are copying from excel to another app- I ran to a similar situation in PowerPoint, I would use this approach (it could be better with [sleep](http://analystcave.com/vba-sleep-vs-wait/) since it's based in mili seconds, depends on your process entirely and what bests suits you)

```
...
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B50").Copy
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Set wrdrng = Doc.Range
.Display
'if it doesn't work above, paste it here (both would be too much time and not really needed)
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
wrdrng.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
...
```

Comment: It is really helpful with your suggestion. I appreaciate that. The VBA code works. =)